# Como fazer slideup/slidedown sem um evento de click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Olá, estou iniciando no AngularJS e estou com algumas dúvidas... Uma delas é essa.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
angular.module('ValueSelling.controllers', []).controller('startController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    jQuery('body').removeClass("page--start page--filter page--favorites page--about page--search page--config page--help");
    jQuery('body').addClass("page--start");
    jQuery('.footer').slideUp();
}).controller('aboutController', function($rootScope, $location) {
    jQuery('body').removeClass("page--start page--filter page--favorites page--about page--search page--config page--help");
    jQuery('body').addClass("page--about");
    jQuery('.footer').slideDown();
    $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
})
```

Gostaria de saber como seria possível remover o jQuery e trocar pelo AngularJS. Todos os exemplos que eu vejo é através de um click. No caso do meu, seria ao carregar o controller.

Answer (score -1):

Maicon, o melhor modo de fazer oque você tais funcionalidades é usar as famosas [Directives do AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Nelas você manipula a DOM como bem entender e ela foi projetada justamente para manipular DOM (inserir html, alterar css e estruturas de html).

```
angular.module('myDirectives', [])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    link: link(scope, element, attrs) {
      //Aqui dentro você possui acesso ao escopo da directive.
      //Element (html tag por exemplo)
      //Attributos que foram utilizados na sua directive.
    }
  };
});
```